# What forums / boards do you use to answer open data questions?

Tags: tool-request, uses-of-open-data

In NYC, we're wondering what forums and web boards do open data professionals use to answer questions around open data?

CartoDB promotes the [GIS Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=nyc).
BetaNYC has a [spreadsheet listing NYC related email lists and websites](https://docs.google.com/a/beta.nyc/spreadsheets/d/1R7O_FZLNB8VV5eoPDNATb-f0njjUsJwmz22cT_OB3fw/edit#gid=1589783907).

Comment: I recommend **Open Data Stack Exchange**, the question and answer site for developers, researchers, and anyone else interested in open data. But you probably already know that one ;)

Comment: Also, your "GIS Stack Exchange" link actually points to Open Data Stack Exchange.

Comment: Could you please detail your requirements, especially what you need that is not already offered by Open Data Stack Exchange? Thanks!

Comment: Nicolas I'm looking for forums that help people understand open data. This site is good but isn't great nor perfect.

Comment: @noneck Suggestions for improvement are always welcome on [Open Data meta](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

This one obviously. I also use http://reddit.com/r/opendata, and more recently the Open Knowledge Foundation's forums (http://discuss.okfn.org/) but that's for a project specific to them so I can't vouch for it as being good for general discussions or questions.

Answer (score 3):

National Institute for Computer-Assisted Reporting, mailing list NICAR is an oldie and a goodie. http://www.ire.org/resource-center/listservs/archives/