# Where can software developers interested in open government data be reached?

Tags: programming

I am looking for most recommended places outside of the open government mailing lists to invite software developers interested in open government data to participate in Poplus.org re-usable civic technology "components" effort.

In particular we are building participation in the Poplus Online group: http://bit.ly/poplusgroup

Suggestions?

Comment: Probably not a duplicate question but similiar, so have a look at this: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4339/what-forums-boards-do-you-use-to-answer-open-data-questions/4365#4365 it will give some pointers. www.reddit.com/r/opendata is particularly good in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

i'll tell you where i lurk:
google groups:
open gov jobs
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/opengovjobs
civic data alliance
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/civicdataalliance
uk gov data developers
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/uk-government-data-developers
linked data api discuss
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/linked-data-api-discuss
code for northern virginia
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nova-brigade
geo dc
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/geonerds-dc
code for dc
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dc-cfa-brigade
code for fort lauderdale
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/code-for-ftl
school of open
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/school-of-open
okfn task force
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/okfn-task-force
open data engagement
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/open-data-engagement
global open data initiative
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/global-open-data-initiative
open civic data
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/open-civic-data
us open gov
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/us-open-government
foia machine
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/foia-machine
open data day
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/open-data-day

your facebook group

reddit:
http://www.reddit.com/r/opendata
http://www.reddit.com/r/opendata_pt
http://www.reddit.com/r/opengov
there's more on reddit if you feel like digging

code for america lets authors post on their tumblr, you could submit a post there

medium seems to be the cool kid blog of the day, you could double down and post it there as well.

code for philly has a linkedin group

every avenue sunlight foundation and okfn offer you: there's a slew of groups and mailing lists

code for hampton roads and code for atlanta have mailing lists, i'm betting most brigades do...

not to mention github.....man there's a ton of groups there.

i know of a few flickr groups but they're most gov-related and you have to be in gov to join...so i couldn't join.

EDIT:
i also keep all of these twitter lists:
https://twitter.com/jalbertbowdenii/lists/civhax
https://twitter.com/jalbertbowdenii/lists/openglam
https://twitter.com/jalbertbowdenii/lists/dotgov
https://twitter.com/jalbertbowdenii/lists/open-acc-sci-edu-glam-kno
https://twitter.com/jalbertbowdenii/lists/open-data-journo-crypto
https://twitter.com/jalbertbowdenii/lists/open-science-stem
https://twitter.com/jalbertbowdenii/lists/data

nicar data journalists mailing list:
http://www.ire.org/resource-center/listservs/subscribe-nicar-l/

knight-mozilla open news:
http://opennews.org/